# Python 3 - doctest module for long .txt files

Tags: python-3.x, function, doctest

I have a quick question regarding the doctest module in Python 3.

I haven't used it yet, just read some information and how they apply it to functions. I have two functions I need to test and I think I understand what I have to do. However, I have no clue how to apply it in my case. I have to functions that work with .txt files. The first one takes a word and the file
path to a text file as input and outputsa list of pairs, each consisting of a
line in which the word occurs and the corresponding line number.

```
def find_all_instances(word, path):
    l = []
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        for position, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
            if word in line:
                tup = (line, position+1)
                l.append(tup)
        return l
print(find_all_instances('word', 'filename.txt'))
```

The second function takes the file path to a text file as input and outputs a
list of pairs, each consisting of a word and the number of times the word occurs
in the text in decreasing order.

```
from collections import Counter
import re

def task_2(inp):
    with open(inp, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        data = (x.lower() for x in re.split(r'[\n, .?!:;-]', f.read()) if x.isalpha())
    cnt = Counter(data)
    return cnt.most_common()

task_2(r"filepath")
```

My question now is: How can I apply this in these cases? Since the examples of doctest that I've seen only use simple functions that for example multiply two inputs. However, in my cases, the output seems to be quite large since the text files are about 10'000 lines long and therefore the output is equally large. How can one implement it for these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you create functions that actually do the job of generating the lists and to document them:

```py
from collections import Counter
import re

def find_all_instances(word, lines):
    """Returns a list of tuples (line, line_number) for the lines where the word appear.

    >>> find_all_instances('test', ['first line', 'second line for test', 'third test line', 'last line'])
    [('second line for test', 2), ('third test line', 3)]

    """
    l = []
    for position, line in enumerate(lines):
        if word in line:
            tup = (line, position+1)
            l.append(tup)
    return l

def word_counter(text):
    """Returns a list of tuples (word, word_counter) for each word in a text, sorted by the most commons.

    >>> word_counter('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\nSed non risus.\n Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor.')
    [('sid', 2), ('adipiscing', 2), ('amet', 2), ('dolor', 2), ('non', 1), ('ipsum', 1), ('ultricies', 1), ('consectetur', 1), ('risus', 1), ('elit', 1), ('nec', 1), ('tortor', 1), ('lorem', 1), ('lectus', 1), ('sed', 1), ('dignissim', 1)]

    """
    data = (x.lower() for x in re.split(r'[\n, .?!:;-]', text) if x.isalpha())
    cnt = Counter(data)
    return cnt.most_common()
```

And then use them in other functions which handle the file opening:

```py
def find_all_instances_from_path(word, path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return find_all_instances(word, file.readlines())

def task_2(inp):
    with open(inp, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        return word_counter(f.read())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I would just split the function into two parts and now apply the tests in the new one? Is it possible to use the doctest on a very large file or is it better to just use a smaller input?

Comment: Your doctest should be representative of your data, if you have any special data. You cannot use a doctest for the functions which open files, as there is no way to provide such files for doctest.